# compilation error: request member in something not a structure of union

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I'm having the above error `request member rv in something not a structure of union`. I've googled it and several answers told me it's when working with a pointer but tries to access it as a struct, where I should be using `->` instead of `.`

```
  int foo(void * arg, struct message * msg)
  {
    struct fd_info * info = (struct something *) arg;
    struct client * csys = info->c_sys;
    int * socks[MAX_CONNECTION];
    int rv;
    socks = &(info->_socks); // where int * _socks[MAX_CONNECTION] in struct info

    // do other things

    rv = sendto(socks[i], msg, sizeof(msg), NULL, &(csys->client_address), sizeof(csys->client_address));
    ...
  }
```

The problem is all of the arguments i have are pointers. i'm confused as to what is wrong. thanks to any comments/thoughts.

EDIT: 
sorry about &msg, it was originally just msg but in my desperate attempt i was trying things.
added definition of rv.

Comment: Are you missing some correct syntax where it says "do other things?"

Comment: Please show the definition of `rv`

Comment: Also, the definition of `csys` might help.

Comment: `sizeof(msg)` returns the size of the pointer `msg` not the size of the buffer `msg` points to.

Comment: Most compilers output line numbers in their error messages.  Can you indicate which line in your example is causing the problem?  If it's at `rv = sendto(...)`, maybe you could add a carriage return after each parameter, which would tell you which expression the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: Thanks Jim, I'll definitely try that method to localize which is the problematic expression.

Answer (score 1):

`msg` is already a pointer.  So perhaps you should have `msg` instead of `&msg`,
and `sizeof(*msg)` instead of `sizeof(&msg)`, in the arguments you're passing to `sendto`?

Comment: sorry about the confusion regarding &msg, it was originally msg but i mistyped it. also sizeof(*msg) does not work, I still get the same error regarding it not being structure or union.

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple problems, but not necessarily the one that is causing your error. You'll need to provide more code and tell us where the error is occurring.

Problems:
1)  why are you using &msg in the call to sendto()? msg is already a pointer. Do you mean to pass a pointer to a pointer?

2) sizeof(&msg) evaluates to the size of a pointer. Is that what you want or do you want the size of the data msg points to?

3) My guess as to the cause of your error is csys. What is it? Is it a pointer or a struct?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the below.

Change the below

```
     int * socks[MAX_CONNECTION];
```

to

```
     int** socks;
     *socks = &(info->_socks);
```

Accessing:

```
     int i = *socks[index];
```

Comment: I actually don't get any errors with this, thanks! But how do I use it to refer to information with an index?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I was looking at wrong line number. I still get the same error.

Comment: Try moving the below declarations to the beggining of the function.

  int * socks[MAX_CONNECTION]; 
  int rv; 

  struct fd_info * info = (struct something *) arg; 
  struct client * csys = info->c_sys;